# How to fix this race condition error?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, race-condition

I have such simple code:

```
class B {
//....
}

public class A {

    private ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, B> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    public void add(B b) {
        long key = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) / 60;

        //this area has bug
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            B oldB = map.get(key);
            // work with oldB
        } else {
            map.put(key, b);
        }
        //end this area
    }
}
```

So, I can get **key** from 2 threads. Then first thread go to else-path. Then second thread is starting. But first thread has not added value yet.

Comment: Use [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-):  `B oldB = map.putIfAbsent(key, b)`  Then check if return value is `null` to determine whether new value was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the area you have marked as "this area has a bug" in a `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized (map) {
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        B oldB = map.get(key);
        // work with oldB
    } else {
        map.put(key, b);
    }
}
```

This prevents two threads with the same `key` value from accessing the map at the same time - but only if all other accesses to the `map` are also `synchronized` with `get` (e.g. you don't have an unsynchronized `map.get` elsewhere in the class).

Note that this prevents all concurrent updates to the map, which might create an unacceptable bottleneck. Whilst you can use `Long.valueOf(key)` to obtain an instance on which you can synchronize, there are no guaranteed ranges of input which are guaranteed to be cached.

Instead, you could perhaps map the `long` into the range of values cached by `Integer.valueOf` (i.e. -128 to 127), which would give you a more granular lock, e.g.

```
// Assuming that your clock isn't stuck in the 1960s...
Integer intKey = Integer.valueOf((int)( (longKey % 255) - 128));
synchronized (intKey) {
  // ...
}
```

(Or, of course, you could maintain your own cache of keys).

Comment: but this is too slow. The method *add* can be called like 1000 times per sec.

Comment: What's your evidence it's too slow?

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you for great reply.

Comment: @James_D I dont do some tests about it. Just my feeling. Maybe I am false about performance issue in this code.

Comment: @Max validate your assumptions.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry, I have one question. Why we need range from -128 to 127 instead of from 0 to 254?

Comment: @Max read the Javadoc of `Integer.valueOf(int)`.

Comment: Be careful what you tell the noobs.  Synchronizing on `map` only prevents other threads from accessing map if _every block of code that accesses it_ is similarly synchronized.  Thinking that synchronizing on an object somehow _locks_ that object (i.e., prevents other threads from using it) is a very common newbie mistake.

Comment: @AndyTurner I see: "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127"

Comment: Synchronizing using `synchronized` on a concurrent structure is not the right approach. If you have to synchronize on the map anyway, you shouldn't use a concurrent map, and if you have a concurrent map, it will have the methods you need without the `synchronized` block.